Get Lon / Lat from geopandas
I'm working of the example below
https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v2.0.0b0/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

ox.__version__

# configure the place, network type, trip times, and travel speed
place = {"city": "Berkeley", "state": "California"}
network_type = "walk"
trip_times = [5]  # in minutes
travel_speed = 4.5  # walking speed in km/hour

# download the street network
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type=network_type)

# find the centermost node and then project the graph to UTM
gdf_nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
x, y = gdf_nodes["geometry"].unary_union.centroid.xy
center_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, x[0], y[0])
Gb = ox.project_graph(G)

# add an edge attribute for time in minutes required to traverse each edge
meters_per_minute = travel_speed * 1000 / 60  # km per hour to m per minute
for _, _, _, data in Gb.edges(data=True, keys=True):
    data["time"] = data["length"] / meters_per_minute


 # get one color for each isochrone
iso_colors = ox.plot.get_colors(n=len(trip_times), cmap="plasma", start=0)   

def make_iso_polys(G, edge_buff=25, node_buff=50, infill=False):
    isochrone_polys = []
    for trip_time in sorted(trip_times, reverse=True):
        subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, center_node, radius=trip_time, distance="time")

        node_points = [Point((data["x"], data["y"])) for node, data in subgraph.nodes(data=True)]
        nodes_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id": list(subgraph.nodes)}, geometry=node_points)
        nodes_gdf = nodes_gdf.set_index("id")

        edge_lines = []
        for n_fr, n_to in subgraph.edges():
            f = nodes_gdf.loc[n_fr].geometry
            t = nodes_gdf.loc[n_to].geometry
            edge_lookup = G.get_edge_data(n_fr, n_to)[0].get("geometry", LineString([f, t]))
            edge_lines.append(edge_lookup)

        n = nodes_gdf.buffer(node_buff).geometry
        e = gpd.GeoSeries(edge_lines).buffer(edge_buff).geometry
        all_gs = list(n) + list(e)
        new_iso = gpd.GeoSeries(all_gs).unary_union

        # try to fill in surrounded areas so shapes will appear solid and
        # blocks without white space inside them
        if infill:
            new_iso = Polygon(new_iso.exterior)
        isochrone_polys.append(new_iso)
    return isochrone_polys


# make the isochrone polygons
isochrone_polys = make_iso_polys(Gb, edge_buff=25, node_buff=0, infill=True)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=isochrone_polys)

# plot the network then add isochrones as colored polygon patches
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(
    G, show=False, close=False, edge_color="#999999", edge_alpha=0.2, node_size=0
)
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color=iso_colors, ec="none", alpha=0.6, zorder=-1)
plt.show()

As far as i understand, the data is first extrated in lon/lat (-122.271, 37.871), but then i get converted into a different format...
Could someone help me understand why the conversion is required and how could i convert isochrone_polys back into lon/lat

In the function make_iso_polys, geopandas.buffer is applied. When the coordinates are in degrees, the distance parameter in geopandas.buffer will be applied in degrees. I suppose this is not wanted in this script (it typically isn't), so I suppose this is the reason the coordinates are first reprojected to UTM so the coordinates are in meter instead of degrees.
You can convert the data back to WGS84 by adding the following line at the end of the script:
gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326)

